# <td> has imaginary middle padding

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

Hello Ive ran into this problem where I cant seem to get the table data border to line up with the border of the  border here is the code:

```
<table id="proxy-list">
    <tr>
      <th>Proxies</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Proxy1</td>
      <td>12.34.54.78.90</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and heres the css:

```
#proxy-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 60%;
  border: 5px solid #e83737;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid #e83737;
  text-align: center;
}
th, td {
  color: #4F8AFF;
}
td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 180px;
  padding-bottom:  100px;
}
```

[image]

Ive been trying to fix this forever Please help!!!!!

Comment: add colspan to your th https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `colspan` attribute to `th` tag. The colspan attribute defines the number of columns a cell should span.
`<th colspan="2">Proxies</th>`

```css
#proxy-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 60%;
  border: 5px solid #e83737;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid #e83737;
  text-align: center;
}
th,
td {
  color: #4f8aff;
}
td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 180px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table id="proxy-list">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Proxies</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Proxy1</td>
    <td>12.34.54.78.90</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set colspan=2 in th header
<table id="proxy-list">
    <tr>
      <th **colspan=2**>Proxies</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Proxy1</td>
      <td>12.34.54.78.90</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```